# How to speedup the Chromium loading process under puppeteer, bypass the proxy check

Tags: performance, puppeteer

When using puppeteer, the Chromium page loading speed is sensibly slow than loading in a normal Chrome.
I can notice some text on the status bar about proxy, which is not seen in a normal Chrome.
Any way to speedup the puppeteer Chromium page laoding? It is a few seconds, but many times.

Answer (score 2):

puppeteer Chromium do the proxy check by default, which is a waste of time if you did not use proxy.
Can disable it by

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  args: ["--proxy-server='direct://'", '--proxy-bypass-list=*'],
});
```

then it will be as fast as normal Chrome